# How do I format multiple free text columns into a single list on Google sheets but keep quantitative data tagged?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I want to group some columns into one list while keeping others as columns if possible. I have a sheet with quantitative data and also multiple qualitative free text answers. I've been asked to format the sheet so that the free text sits under the same column heading and has the quantitative data attached. Hopefully the images explain the desired format, is this possible?

[Original format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdsRv.png)

[Desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPprH.png)

I tried the transpose formula, however its not what I need. I need the structure of table to stay the same and the free columns to sit in the same list. The quantitative data can duplicate.

My solution currently is to duplicate the sheet as many times as free text questions (i.e. 3 free text questions = 3 copies of the sheet). I keep 1 free text question on each sheet and rename that column the same on each sheet i.e. "All qualitative data". I then copy and paste the 3 tables under each other to create 1 table with 1 free text column.

Answer (score 0):

Well simple solution is to just utilize the properties of arrays separated by a semicolon `;`. This is essentially 3 different tables that are being stacked.

```
={QUERY(A1:F,"SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE A IS NOT NULL");QUERY(A2:F,"SELECT A,B,C,E WHERE A IS NOT NULL");QUERY(A2:F,"SELECT A,B,C,F WHERE A IS NOT NULL")}
```

[image: Example]